# (android) How can i listen a value from a website ? After it is changed, i want to send a notification to users

Tags: android, event-handling, listener, action

I am planning create an Android application. I will follow a value of variable. After it is changed, i wanna send a notification to users. But this listening **should not** be work background all times because of battery, should wake up when the value is changed or it should check time to time the variable. Are there anything for this in Android programming ? (the website is 3rd party, not my website)

Comment: Is this your website or a 3rd party that you're following?

Comment: it is 3rd party @dharms

Comment: Unless they offer an API, this is not possible without doing a background service that periodically checks the website for a change.

Comment: they dont offer any api. i wanna send notification as soon as possible, for this my checking time should be short minutes,for example checking every 5-10 mins. if i do that, it will affect the battery badly.

Comment: Well unfortunately there isn't magic included with the Android SDK...

Comment: The only other option I can give you is you set up your own server that does the monitoring of the website. You can have a push notification server associated with that and have your app subscribe. Sorry, but there are just some technical hurdles you can't overcome with this.

Comment: i will research this option, server and monitoring the website. thanks for idea. And, what if i accept checking every 10-15 mins, which function should i use? can you give a website link for this.